# How to define complex tree structure interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I had learned some typical interface for simple tree structure, like:

```
export type Tree<T> = T & {
  children?: T[];
}
```

But troubled when leaf node attributes are different with parent node attributes.

In my usage scene:

- Parent node has one attribute: `groupName`
- Leaf node has two attributes: `fileName` and `uniqueId`

So I define tree structure like this:

```
export type Tree = {
  isGroup: true;
  groupName: string;
  children: Tree[];
} | {
  isGroup: false;
  fileName: string;
  uniqueId: number;
}
```

In my opinion, there are 2 disadvantages about this tree structure type:

1. It is necessary to accurately determine whether each node is `Group` in Recursive traversal. However, it's better to accurately determine only by `children`. (looks like `isGroup` is a little redundant)
2. No Template Literal Types

Is there a better way to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have handle it like this:

```js
export type Branch = {
  children: Tree[];
};

export type Twig = {
  fileName: string;
  uniqueId: number;
};

type Either<X, Y> =
  | ({
      [KX in keyof X]: X[KX];
    } & {
      [KY in Exclude<keyof Y, keyof X>]?: never;
    })
  | ({
      [KY in keyof Y]: Y[KY];
    } & {
      [KX in Exclude<keyof X, keyof Y>]?: never;
    });

export type Tree = Either<Branch, Twig>;
```

This way you won't need the `isGroup`, which as you pointed, its redundant. And will ensure there are no objects having properties from both like this

```js
const tree: Tree = {
    fileName: "",
    children: [
        {
            fileName: "",
            uniqueId: 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

and the `Exclude` is necessary in case both types have common properties

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCUCGA7AxgCzgF44BvAKDjgIEsAbAEymGwC44AVZ4AbQF0A3OQC+Q8qEiwEyVBwDuNAObEylOADN6wAHKYAtsHYBnGFBrZFQqgFdsNAI7XgASQbts1vQCNgUIaPJyJBQ4AFEaGHxfAB4ADQAaOABNAD5iNQAfOAAKCip8uB4AaVi4czgAa2BECHU4WL52WOKGq3zhOAAyVQKqYqSy7DCQXDprBmBoqpq6pMTp2vqUvgB+d2AAN182qmEASkycvN7+wcrqxaTG5P7BNV2unpOSs9CRsYmpi7qE85nk5ZrODYTbbe5wfZiCTQeDBWTcFThSIxDA4AiJeRKFJiXAQbAmBDcdhcYCoEjHWiMZhsQrg44FTR0HT6QxwABEbPi4JsdkcLjccAAjFyCsIRfl6flKUwWOweNyJQqGVpdAZ2Bzxb18rYHE5XOwACya3pipVPLVURnMtXszlmnm6-nsADMxtFbrgfGNpqoXpEQiAA)